# A contest problem in geometry to find triangle ratio $EG$ to $GF$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

The question is taken from IMO 1988:

> Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with $AB =$ $12$ and $AC =$ $16.$ Suppose $M$ is the
>   midpoint of side $BC$ and points $E$ and $F$ are chosen on sides $AC$ and
>   $AB$ respectively, and suppose that the lines $EF$ and $AM$ intersect at
>   $G.$ If $AE = 2AF$ then find the ratio $EG/GF$

I have tried this question a lot but I fail to solve it .I tried construction like:

1. A line from $F$ to $X$ on $AC$ such that it divide $AE$ into equal halves.But I cant figure out anything from this approach .
2. I constructed a line parallel to $BC$ from $F$ to $AC$ but it also doesnt help.

Please guide with correct approach and solution .(I think similarity, Appolinus theorem and several constructions would help us to solve but I am not able to crack how)

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Let [.] denotes triangle areas. Then,

$$\frac{FG}{GE}=\frac{[AFM]}{[AEM]} = \frac{\frac{AF}{AB}[ABM]}{\frac{AE}{AC}[ACM]}
=\frac{AF}{AE}\cdot\frac{AC}{AB}= \frac12\cdot \frac{16}{12} = \frac23$$

Comment: How do you say this $$\frac{FG}{GE}=\frac{[AFM]}{[AEM]}$$ I cant see

Comment: @AkshajBansal - Because triangles AFM and AEM share the same base AM, their area ratio is proportional to heights, which is proportional to FG:GE.